# Remove items from array (Restkit project with JSON from API)

Tags: ios, arrays, json, restkit

I have an array of `leafs`, and I would like to remove some of the objects in the array.

There are around **50 objects in the array, and I only want about 10 of them in the array**; the 10 objects wanted in the array are mixed through out the 50 objects in the array.

*I'm using RestKit in my project, and putting the `leafs` into a Table View.*

ViewController.m

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *springs;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *leafs;

@end

@synthesize tableView=_tableView;
@synthesize springs;
@synthesize leafs;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self configureRestKit];
    [self loadLeafs];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)configureRestKit {
    // initialize AFNetworking HTTPClient
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.e.com"];
    AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

    // initialize RestKit
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];

    // setup object mappings
    RKObjectMapping *springMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Spring class]];
    [springMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"name"]];

    RKObjectMapping *leafMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Leaf class]];
    [leafMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[@"abbreviation", @"shortName", @"id"]];

    [springMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"leafs" toKeyPath:@"leafs" withMapping:leafMapping]];

// Wain, this is where I'm getting that error:
// "property discardsinvalidobjectsoninsert not found on object of type RKObjectMapping"
springMapping.discardsInvalidObjectsOnInsert = YES;

    // register mappings with the provider using a response descriptor
    RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor =
    [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:springMapping
                                                 method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                            pathPattern:nil
                                                keyPath:@"springs"
                                            statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
    [objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
}

- (void)loadLeafs {
    NSString *apikey = @kCLIENTKEY;

    NSDictionary *queryParams = @{@"apikey" : apikey,};

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"v1/springs/"
                                           parameters:queryParams
                                              success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                                  springs = mappingResult.array;
                                                  [self.tableView reloadData];


                                              }
                                              failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                  NSLog(@"No springs?': %@", error);
                                              }];
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return springs.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    Spring *spring = [springs objectAtIndex:section];
    return spring.leafs.count;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    Spring *spring = [springs objectAtIndex:section];
    return spring.name;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"standardCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    Spring *spring = [spring objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    Leaf *leaf = [spring.leafs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = leaf.shortName;

    return cell;
}
```

Spring.h

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *id;
@property (nonatomic) NSArray *leafs;
```

Leaf.h

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *abbreviation;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *shortName;
@property (nonatomic) NSNumber *id;
```

**Per Wain, I added this in my Spring.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL discardsInvalidObjectsOnInsert;
```

**Per Wain, I added this sort of thing in my Spring.m**

```
- (BOOL)validateName:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError {

    if([(NSString *)*ioValue  isEqualToString:@"cricket"]){

        NSLog(@"old name: %@, new name: %@", self.name, *ioValue);

// Wain: set the names to nil for the objects you don't want
ioValue = nil;

        return NO;

// Wain: should I keep this line?
        self.discardsInvalidObjectsOnInsert = YES;

        }

        else{
            return YES;
        }

}
```

**Per Wain, I added this in my ViewController.m**

```
- (void)loadLeafs {

    NSString *apikey = @kCLIENTKEY;

    NSDictionary *queryParams = @{@"apikey" : apikey,};

        [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] getObjectsAtPath:@"v1/springs/"
                                               parameters:queryParams
                                                  success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
                                                      springs = mappingResult.array;
                                                      [self.tableView reloadData];


                                                  }
                                                  failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                      NSLog(@"No springs?': %@", error);
                                                  }];
        // Wain: filter (using a predicate) the mapping array (name != nil)
        NSPredicate *bPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithValue:NO];
        self.filteredArray = [self.sports filteredArrayUsingPredicate:bPredicate];
    }
```

**Success Block**

```
NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name != nil"];
                                                  springs = [mappingResult.array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate];

                                                  // You need to loop over the springs after you filter them and then filter the leafs of each spring
                                                  for (Spring *spring in springs) {
                                                      for (Leaf *leaf in spring.leafs){
                                                          NSPredicate *filterPredicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"shortName != nil"];
                                                          leafs = [spring.leafs filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate2];
                                                      }
                                                  }

                                                  [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Create a new NSMutableArray, loop through your array, add the ones you want to the new array?

Comment: What criteria do you use to determine if you want to remove a leaf or not?

Comment: @Mike Good question, I'll make that clear in my original question too.  I want to specify of the `leafs` what `shortName`s to include.  For example, in the `leafs` array, I only want the `shortName`s: aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd, eee.  Does that make it clear?

Comment: @jraede thanks for the response!  Do you have a link for how to do that, or can you post a snippet of code?  I kinda understand the general idea of what I need to try to do as well, but specific implementation is where I'm coming up short here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at using KVC validation with RestKit if you want to filter the items out during mapping.

If you want all the items to be available on the device and only filter for display, use a predicate to filter the array.

Comment: If I use a predicate, does that go in the `loadLeafs` method, or in the `tableView` method, or something else?

Comment: Currently I tried adding 3 lines to do predicate inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` after `Leaf *leaf = [spring.leafs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` but before `cell.textLabel.text = leaf.shortName;`, but its not quite working: `NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"leaf.shortName CONTAINS %@", @"BBB" ];
    NSArray *filtered  = [leafs filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSLog(@"Filter: %@", filtered);`

Comment: Generally you run the predicate and cache the result, usually in a method called in `viewWillAppear:` and anytime the source data changes (RestKit success block is called). In any case, before the table methods as you need to give the filtered count to the table view...

Comment: So in my original question above, I updated the code in 3 parts to reflect what I think you were saying.  1 - added `filterLeafs` method.  2 - added `viewWillAppear` that calls `filterLeafs` method.  3 - called `filterLeafs` at the end of the success block.  Is that what you were saying basically?  When I NSLog in my `filterLeafs` method, I get `null` back for both `filtered` array and also `leafs` array, which surprised me since `leagues` works fine in the table view?

Comment: Note down on a piece of paper the data you have and how you're organising it. With the response from RestKit you save `springs = mappingResult.array;` - not leafs. So, when you then try to use leafs it is nil. You're calling in the correct place, just not setting up the data first. As you have leafs in each section you should create a new list of springs including only the leafs you need. --- BUT - use KVC and RestKit can do it for you much more easily...

Comment: Yeah I couldn't use `springs` because it wasn't a mutable array, even though I'd like to pull some items out of that array too.  And I can't change it to NSArray instead of mutable because it would mess up the other parts of the VC like `springs = mappingResult.array`.  So thats why I feel like I'm in a pickle with that, and am not sure how to get it where I want to

Comment: And I'm trying out the KVC in `Spring.m` with some sample code, but it won't even work (trying to get it to be Uppercase) `- (BOOL)validateTitle:(id *)ioValue error:(NSError **)outError {
    *ioValue = [(NSString*)*ioValue uppercaseString];
    return YES;
}`.  So I'm at a loss there too

Comment: Your code in the question doesn't show a `title` property. Do you mean `name`?

Comment: Oh shoot, wow that made them uppercase!  Ok so now I kinda have a feel for how this works.  So I want it to say if name equals "cricket", remove "cricket" from the array.  This is what I'm trying, can you help guide me where I'm missing something? `if ([(NSString*)*ioValue something] == @"cricket") {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;`

Comment: I'm not sure what `something` should be, or if I'm doing that whole method right. But I think what it's saying in code (once I figure out what `something` should be), is if the string equals cricket, don't return it.

Comment: I think I might have gotten something working finally, added code in my original question at the bottom!

Comment: Marked your answer, thanks so much for the help.  Real quick question, it just leaves a blank `tableViewCell` now, how do I get rid of that `tableViewCell`?

Comment: Because I guess I meant for that part to implicitly go hand-in-hand with my question

Comment: Because at the moment you only reject the title, not the object. Turn on `discardsInvalidObjectsOnInsert` on the mapping and make the required `name` non-optional in the model (then when you reject the name the whole object will be rejected with it).

Comment: So to "turn on" `discardsInvalidObjectsOnInsert` I did two things: 1 - added `@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL discardsInvalidObjectsOnInsert;` to my Spring.h, 2 - added `self.discardsInvalidObjectsOnInsert = YES;` in my Spring.m at the end of the `validateName` method.  Did I figure that correct, or is there something else there too?

Comment: As for the second part of your response, I'm not sure: what sort of code you're talking about exactly -and- if you're talking about it going into the `validateName` method in the `Spring.m` file or if it goes somewhere else?

Comment: `discardsInvalidObjectsOnInsert` is a property you set on the mapping (google it). Optional is a setting on each attribute in the core data model.

Comment: I did google it and there wasn't much coming up for it, thats the reason for the question.  Only two total google pages, and those were a lot of the same or not quite relevant.  https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&q=discardsInvalidObjectsOnInsert&rls=en    .... The only two that seemed close were https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1491  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508146/restkit-data-synchronization-post-local-deletion-issue.  So that's where I tried to work off of and figure it out, but couldn't tell for sure, so that was my reason to ask you?

Comment: So when you say its a property to set on the mapping, are you talking about inside my ViewController file in `configureRestKit` then?

Comment: If you are verifying the spring name: `springMapping.discardsInvalidObjectsOnInsert = YES;` and set not optional on the name attribute in the model.

Comment: I tried doing `springMapping.discardsInvalidObjectsOnInsert = YES;` in my ViewController.m, but it gives me the error `property discardsinvalidobjectsoninsert not found on object of type RKObjectMapping`.  I put that line of code right after my `springMapping` was created in `configureRestKit` method.  Added the code to my original question so you could see.  Is it only for `RKEntityMapping` or something?

Comment: Yes, only for `RKEntityMapping` (because that is the only one placing into Core Data).

Comment: I didn't add Core Data previously. So is there no way to use your answer unless I add Core Data, or how do you suggest I proceed?  How do I use your answer without adding a bunch of extra stuff?

Comment: Is it as simple as something like swapping out RKObjectManager for RKEntityMapping?

Comment: Ok, sorry, I fought you were using Core Data. When not using Core Data you would simply set the `name`s to nil for the objects you don't want and then filter (using a predicate) the mapping array (`name != nil`)

Comment: Would you suggest I set the `name`s to `nil` in my `Spring.h` class method `(BOOL)validateName:`? And should I do the predicate after the `responseDescriptor` in my `configureRestKit` method -or- after the `getObjectsAtPath` success/failure block in `loadLeafs`?

Comment: I updated the code in my original question trying to give a shot in the dark to what you're recommendation was, see some changes I should make (because some of the code is wrong I'm sure but it was my best shot)?

Comment: Yes, validate name and inside the success block. So change `springs = mappingResult.array;` to `springs = [mappingResult.array filteredArray...`;

Comment: That works perfectly for `springs`, I use: `NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name != nil"]; springs = [mappingResult.array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate];'

Comment: However, `leafs` is nested inside of that, so when I tried to do the same thing, it crashed on me.  I tried: `NSPredicate *filterPredicate2 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"shortName != nil"];
                                                  springs = [mappingResult.array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate2];`

Comment: Obviously it seems to be crashing because I'm doing `springs =` twice, so my question is: How do I do `filtereredArrayUsingPredicate:` with 2 predicates (`filterPredicate` and `filterPredicate2`)?

Comment: I tried this but it still crashed: `NSPredicate *compoundPredicate = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[filterPredicate, filterPredicate2]];
                                                  springs = [mappingResult.array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:compoundPredicate];`

Comment: You aren't trying to filter the same thing twice. You need to loop over the springs after you filter them and then filter the leafs of each spring.

Comment: Updated my code in the code above titled Success Block; I'm still not doing it quite right but feel like I'm really close, can you give me some guidance on where to tweak it?

Comment: Remove `for (Leaf *leaf in spring.leafs){`. Change `leafs = [spring.leafs...` to `spring.leafs = [spring.leafs...`

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do what you are asking is as follows:

```
for (Leaf *leaf in leafs) {
    if (![leaf.shortName isEqualToString:@"aaa"] && ![leaf.shortName isEqualToString:@"bbb"] && ![leaf.shortName isEqualToString:@"ccc"] && ![leaf.shortName isEqualToString:@"ddd"]) {
        [leafs removeObject:leaf];
    }
}
```

That basically loops through your array of leaf objects, and if it comes across a leaf object with a shortName property that is anything other than those four strings, that object will be removed.

Comment: That makes sense, where do I put that in my ViewController though?

Comment: perhaps in loadLeafs? Not knowing anything else about your code I can't give you the best answer.

Comment: I tried it in `loadLeafs`, and posted my code in my question above, that I tried, but it didn't remove anything I asked it to.  Any ideas or any more details that would help?

Comment: Firstly, you don't want to put that for-loop inside the other loop where you loop through springs. Take it out and do it after. Secondly, right add NSLog(@"%@", leafs); before and after you run through the loop and tell me what the output is.

Comment: NSLog is `null` both times inside of that method.  Assuming that might have something to do with `springs = mappingResult.array` being what gets loaded in there, hence me trying to figure out how to get the `leafs` that is nested inside of `springs`?

Comment: Where/how do you create your mutable dictionary?

Comment: I have the model classes `Spring.h` and `Leaf.h`.  Then I create a property in the ViewController `leafs`.  Then in the tableView I use `spring.leafs`

Comment: Without any more information all I'll recommend is you make sure your mutable array is created properly: NSMutableArray *leafs = [NSMutableArray array]; Once you do that the array has been created and you can add.remove objects from it.

Comment: @Mike Yeah its just that I'm seeing a warning next to every `leafs` line saying `Local declaration of leafs hides instance variable`.  Any idea why that's popping up?